# mod_perl use request input properties in output? pnote?

Tags: perl, mod-perl2

Using mod_perl2, I'm trying to access the request args
e.g.

```
$r->args()
```

in an output filter.  Is it possible?

I considered using [pnotes](http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/api/Apache2/RequestUtil.html#C_pnotes_) however if i store the pnote reference against the request ($r) how do I retrieve it in the output filter?  It seems like [r](http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/api/Apache2/Filter.html#C_r_) is not available to me in an output filter.

Answer (score 0):

A brief check of the docs suggest access to Apache2::RequestRec ($r) is fine, with code xamples.

http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/user/handlers/filters.html#HTTP_Request_Output_Filters

Comment: In that example, is $r the filter rather than the request? I'm new to Pearl so I appologise if this is a silly q.

http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/api/Apache2/Filter.html